# Batch multi step and/or form multi step in sonata admin bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I have make search but I found nothing that help me. I use sonata admin bundle and first I want to know if it's possible to make multi step form.
Second, I'd like to make a new batch action (this step is ok for me), but after user chose the batch action I want a form with field that I can use in my custom batch action.

I have see it's possible to add field next the batch action list but this field are visible for all batch action for me I would like the user first chose the batch action and then see field on a other page for example the confirmation one.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

### Multi steps form

I found this bundle [CraueFormFlowBundle](https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle) but i never test it. 
You could try use the [jquery-steps front-end library](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples) with sonata and custom template for the edit/create view by generate js with js.twig files.

### Batch action

For the batch action, you could use redirection in your code batch action logic